# c# using indexofany for the decimal point and restricting only to one decimal point

Tags: c#, calculator

```
  `private void Dot_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)            
        {          
            if (NumBox1.Text.IndexOfAny(char['.'])
            {

            }`
```

I think the solution for the restriction of one decimal point is here.

`if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NumBox1.Text)
    {

    numbox1.text = "0" + ".";
    }
            }`

this is when the textbox is empty. Then I clicked dot sign to get automatically a result of "0." inside the textbox. But, it only returns "."

Comment: That's not how you define a `char[]`. You want something like `new char[]{'.'}`. Though in this case you don't need an array.

Comment: in order to restrict to integers you can use [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) or [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: You are checking if the text is null, and if it isn't you search it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you've got `char['.']` at all, or what you expect it to mean. I suspect you just want the character literal `'.'` and use `IndexOf`.

```
else if (NumBox1.Text.IndexOf('.') == -1 && ...)
```

You only want to use `IndexOfAny` if you're looking for *multiple* things, in which case you'd want something like:

```
IndexOfAny(new[] { '.', ',' })
```

Or even more simply:

```
else if (!NumBox1.Text.Contains(".") && ...)
```

I strongly suspect that your conditions really aren't what you want - basically at the moment you'll *always* set the textbox value to "0." if you don't have a dot (ignoring any previous input), and `NumBox1.Text` will *never* be `null` - but you need to work through that for yourself.

EDIT: Using a single call to `IndexOf` isn't going to tell you if there's more than one occurrence of `.`. One simple way to do that is:

```
if (text.IndexOf('.') != text.LastIndexOf('.'))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly isn't that what c# uses for like extracting an char? is "." a char or an int?

Comment: @MAG - `"."` is a `string`. `'.'` is a `char`. There is no `int` anywhere.

Comment: @MAG: Additionally to Corak's (correct) comment, what do you mean by "extracting"?

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry poor choice of word. It's more like the dot button will be able to identify if the textbox already has a decimal sign. thus restricting it to only one decimal point.

Comment: I'm getting another error. it says cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'
`else if (NumBox1.Text.IndexOf('.'))
                {
                    NumBox1.Text = "0" + ".";
                }`

Comment: @MAG: Whoops, yes - I've fixed that. It's not clear what you're trying to do with `IndexOf` to be honest - whether you want to go into that block if it *does* contain a `.` or if it *doesn't*. I've guessed.

Comment: @JonSkeet haha.. I messed up. that part of the indexof is I think where the solution for the restriction of one decimal point will be. I'll fix the question.

Comment: @MAG: Well `IndexOf` isn't going to tell you if there's *more* than one occurrence. I'll edit something for that into the answer.